# Pass URL param to Superset and use is Jinja SQL query

Tags: apache-superset

I have an embedded Superset dashboard using the Superset Embed SDK:

```
supersetEmbeddedSdk.embedDashboard({
        id: '<my-dashboard-id>',
        supersetDomain: 'http://<my-url>:8088',
        mountPoint: document.getElementById('container'),
        fetchGuestToken: () =>
            '<guest-token>',
    })
```

I want to pass a value `hashed_team_id` that I can then use in my chart's dataset sql query: ie

```
SELECT * from example
WHERE 1=1 
AND teams.hashed_team_id = '{{ hashed_team_id }}'
```

I'm wanting to load the iframe showing the dashboard with the proper data in the chart based on the authenticated user on my web app (laravel web app). I can grab the authenticated users hashed team ID in my blade template file `{{ auth()->user()->currentTeam->hashed_team_id }}`

I just need a way to pass that to the dataset jinja query in Superset. I read that you can access url parameters and in jinja do `{{ url_param('your_custom_parameter') }}`, but I don't see how to set a url parameter using the Superset Embed SDK. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I solved using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superset-embedded-sdk) "alternative extension" from the original superset-sdk instead using the default one

Then simply passing inside the `dashboardUiConfig` the data that i would need to rescue with the jinja `{{ url_param() }}`  function as `urlParams`

**Example:**

Importing the SDK like this:
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/superset-embedded-sdk"></script>`

Then in the function

```js
supersetEmbeddedSdk.embedDashboard({
    id: '<dashboard-uuid>',
    supersetDomain: '<superset-domain>',
    mountPoint: document.getElementById('container-superset'),
    fetchGuestToken: () => <guest-token>,
    dashboardUiConfig: {
        urlParams: {
            foo: 'bar',
            id: 1234
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please tell me details. How to set chart with filter: teams.hashed_team_id = '{{ hashed_team_id }}'